# build takes very long time on API version 18

Tags: android, build

As long as I set the minSdkVersion to 21 everything is fine. But as soon as I set it to 18, the build takes like 18 minutes on my Macbook Pro (2016).
Especially transformClassesWithDexForFullDebug takes like forever.

my build gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId “my.android.app”
        //Todo: change to 18 for final export. Having minSdkVersion 21 reduces build time significantly
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.5.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "my.android.app.MockTestRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", “MyApp-v$versionName")
        multiDexEnabled true
//        externalNativeBuild {
//            ndk {
//                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
//            }
//        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug{
            // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix "-demo"
            resValue "string", "app_name", “Appname Demo"
        }
        full {
            resValue "string", "app_name", “Appname”
        }
    }
    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }

//    externalNativeBuild {
//        ndkBuild {
//            path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
//        }
//    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }

    maven{
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}

dependencies {
    def supportLibVersion = '25.3.1'
    def playServicesVersion = '10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Utils
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.9'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$playServicesVersion"

    //UI
    compile "com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //Used to create Picasso instance wrapping a custom OkHttp client for testing
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

    //API calls
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'

    //Views injection
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"

    //Analytics
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$playServicesVersion"

    //Crash reporting
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Debug database
    debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    debugCompile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'

    //Testing
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //For recyclerview actions
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Mockito and other dependencies to mock api calls
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.2-beta'
    androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4"
    androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4"
    androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4"

    //Library that allows waiting for retrofit calls with espresso
    androidTestCompile ('com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

    androidTestCompile 'com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-library:1.3.1'

}
```

I am looking for a way to bring down the compilation time to max 5 minutes. My guess is that it would help a lot if I could figure out what transformClassesWithDexForFullDebug actually really does on a granular level, which would allow me to remove those library dependencies which are causing this insane build time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem and the reason why many developers use minSdkVersion 21 for debug builds. I myself have two productFlavors, one with minSdkVersion 15 and one with 21. I use the one with minSdkVersion 21 for my day-to-day work, because it builds so much faster than API 15. 18 minutes is extreme though, what is your build time on API 21?

See also: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html
"When developing your app, you should deploy to a device running Android 7.0 (API level 24) or higher whenever possible."

Comment: API 21: around 54 seconds

Comment: Sorry @Frank but you just explained what I already knew. I am looking for a solution. To wait 18 minutes for each build is not an option for me.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a direct answer. It's a crazy difference. You could start with checking if building a production build for <21 takes so long as well. You can try removing the splits block, so you create only one APK. You can try removing jni.srcDirs (why is it there? are you building native code as well?)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to bring down build time to 2.5 minutes by removing all directories inside ~/.gradle/

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/
```